# How to filter docker image prune by repository?

Tags: docker

I want to prune only docker images from a specific repository and want to use filters to achieve this.

I can do:

```
docker image ls --filter=reference='git.server.com:5000/my/repo'
```

and it lists the right images. But when I try:

```
docker image prune --all --filter=reference='git.server.com:5000/my/repo'
```

I get:

> Error response from daemon: Invalid filter 'reference'

Why is this? And how can I achieve my filter with prune?

Comment: what if you put everything after the `filter=` in double quotes?

Comment: Same error message. And the filter works with `docker image ls` without double quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `docker image prune` only works with `until` and `label` filters, this is mentioned in the [docker docs official](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/)

Comment: Ok, so now I add a label at build time and filter by label later.